# Convert all non-string columns to string

Tags: python-polars

I got a polars.DataFrame object `data_frame` with mutlitple columns - strings and non-strings (like follows), an object where I want to cast all columns to strings:

```
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs
data_frame = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'b': range(3), 'c': [.1, .2, .3]})

non_string_columns = [col for col in data_frame.columns if data_frame[col].dtype != pl.Utf8]
for col in non_string_columns:
    data_frame = data_frame.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Utf8))
```

However this should be possible with the cs selector as well, something like:

```
data_frame.with_columns(~cs.string().as_expr().cast(pl.Utf8))
```

which does not cut it `polars.exceptions.SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected Boolean, got str`

What is the the way to cast many columns at once into stirng (utilising the polars parallelism) with `cs` selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~` is coming last in the order of operations, trying to negate a string expression instead of the selector. Force the right order with some extra parentheses:

```py
data_frame.with_columns((~cs.string()).cast(pl.Utf8))
```

(No need for `as_expr` here, either.)

Answer (score 2):

Without the selectors module, you could also use [`pl.exclude()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.exclude.html#polars.exclude)

```py
df.with_columns(pl.exclude(pl.Utf8).cast(str))
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 0   ┆ 0.1 │
│ b   ┆ 1   ┆ 0.2 │
│ c   ┆ 2   ┆ 0.3 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```